# trying to export data by city from csv to text

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to export data of different years that is grouped by city from a csv to a text file using python but i am not sure how to go about it

having a csv file eg

```
year    rainfall   city
2019      20         A
2019      10         B
2018      18         A
2018       9         B
```

```py
import pandas as pd #used for other function in program
data = pd.read_csv(file.csv)
...
city=[]
for col in csv.columns:
   if "city" in col.lower():
   citylist = list(csv[col])
      for ct in citylist:
         if ct not in city:
           city.append(ct)

for numcity in city
    textfile= open(file.txt,"w")
    textfile.write()
    textfile.close

The outcome trying to achieve

A.txt
year   rainfall   city
2019      20        A
2018      18        A

B.txt
year   rainfall   city
2019      10        A
2018       9        A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to split dataframe by city, you can use `groupby`:

```
for city, grp in data.groupby("city"):
    grp.to_csv(city + ".txt", index=False, sep="\t")
```

Comment: i have a syntax error because of the 'f' i assume this is done python 3? sorry for not stating that i am currently running python 2.7. after reading up the data.groupby i understand more now thank you for help

Comment: @zul Yes, f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. Fixed the code for older versions